# IPython Notebook で書いたコードをGitで管理するには?

Tags: git, python

[IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/index.html) で書いたコードをGitで管理したいのですが、
`*.ipynb`をコミットすると差分が見にくくて辛いです。

セル単位でコードが実行できる利点を残しながら、
Gitで差分が把握しやすい方法はないものでしょうか。

Comment: 上等なコミュニティを築くために、十分と思われる回答に＋１を、解決する回答に承認をお願いします。こちら[「回答が承認されたとはどういう意味ですか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)をご覧ください。

Answer (score 3):

ソース：[こちら（英語）](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-notebooks-under-version-control)の人気ある質問

iPythonを使っていないですが、まだ答えが出てないので見つけたことを知らせします。  
今のところ（２０１４年１２月）はちゃんとしたやり方がないみたいですが、以下の①でなんとできそうです。  
そして解決②でそろそろiPythonそのままでできそうです。

---

①　コミットと差分を普通通りにできるようなやり方。[ソース（英語）](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20844506/377366)

1. gitフィルターを作成します。例えば： `~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py`

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/python

   import sys
   from IPython.nbformat.current import read, write

   json_in = read(sys.stdin, 'json')

   for sheet in json_in.worksheets:
       for cell in sheet.cells:
           if "outputs" in cell:
               cell.outputs = []
           if "prompt_number" in cell:
               cell.prompt_number = ''

   write(json_in, sys.stdout, 'json')
   ```
2. そのファイルを実行可能に変更します：　`chmod +x ~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py`
3. `~/.gitattributes`に追加または新規で作成します

   ```
   *.ipynb    filter=dropoutput_ipynb
   ```
4. 以下のコマンドでgitフィルターを設定します:

   ```
   git config --global core.attributesfile ~/.gitattributes
   git config --global filter.dropoutput_ipynb.clean ~/bin/ipynb_output_filter.py
   git config --global filter.dropoutput_ipynb.smudge cat
   ```

問題点：

- **コミットしたら出力データが残りません！**
- ソースであとの細かいこともあります。

---

②　iPythonそのままで。[ソース（英語）](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6896)

こちらはまだはっきり理解していませんが、みんなにこの問題で困っているようなので、いつかきっと解決すると思います。
使い方を聞きましたので答えが出ましたらここでアップします。

Comment: 日本語を一部修正しました。英語版の回答を参考にした際は、今回のようにソースをリンクで示して頂ければ良いと思います。

Comment: @tomute ありがとうございました